# Setting host -h entry in docker-compose.yml file to update /etc/hosts for docker container

Tags: docker, makefile, localhost, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to bring up some docker containers.
What i want is that my /etc/hosts file in one of the container look like the following:

```
#IDEAL VERSION
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  hbase-docker
```

But when I do docker-compose up. My container has the following:

```
#CURRENTLY WHAT I HAVE
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.2  05528a9c5ca3
```

Notice the LAST LINE. "05528a9c5ca3" is the ID of the container. I'd like it to be 'hbase-docker'. If I was to launch the container as following:

```
docker run -p 2181:2181 --name=hbase-docker -h hbase-docker -d -v $data_dir:/data hbase-docker
```

Then this works... It takes the -h flag and sets the host. 
My question is.. How do I do this in docker-compose.yml.

I'd like it to do it at the time of provisioning, rather than script that runs after if possible. Any ideas?

Just for reference, my docker-compose.yml entry is:

```
version: '2'

services:
 hbase-docker:
  container_name: hbase-docker
  ports:
  - "2181:2181"
  build:
   dockerfile: "Dockerfile-5.6"
   context: "./hbase-docker/"
```

Answer (score 1):

just add extra value `hostname`

```
version: '2'

services:
 hbase-docker:
  hostname: hbase-docker
  container_name: hbase-docker
  ports:
  - "2181:2181"
  build:
   dockerfile: "Dockerfile-5.6"
   context: "./hbase-docker/"
```

[here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts) is for further reading on `extra_hosts`

Comment: Great! Your suggestion solved my problem with a soap service inside a docker container :-)